# How to get only text from given HTML and Replace using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, regex, string, autocomplete

I need help in jquery. Thanks in advance.

I am using autocomplete function of jquery. There is a option for highlight. as like :-

```
highlight: function(match, keywords) {
            return match.replace(new RegExp("("+keywords+")", "gi"),'<b>$1</b>');
        }
```

It is working fine.. But i am getting result in HTML form. as like :-

```
<div id='22048,63' style='width:200px;text-align:left;'><div class='floatleft' style='width:165px'>(LAS) Las Vegas McCarran International Airport, Las Vegas, Nevada</div><div class='floatright' style='width:20px;padding-right:15px;'><img src='images/plane.gif' width='14' height='16' /></div></div>
```

Thats why if i enter in textbox "las" than it is replacing the class attribute from HTML and than my design has mashed up. Because "las" keyword is appearing in "Class". So it is replacing this.

I want only replace text that i got in HTML.

Than tell me there is any option in jquery so i can do this..

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Check out my answer, you can use `.text()` function to strip all the HTML Tags. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.text()` function to get just the text without the HTML Tags. Example:

```
function removeAllHtmlInsideDiv() {
    $(".example_1").html( $(".example_1").text() );
};
removeAllHtmlInsideDiv();
```

In your case, it can be used as:

```
highlight: function(match, keywords) {
    return (match.replace(new RegExp("("+keywords+")", "gi"),'<b>$1</b>')).text();
}
```

**For Stripping HTML Tags from String:**

```
function stripHTML(html)
{
    // var html = "<p>Some HTML</p>";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
    return text;
}
```

So in your case, you need to put this way:

```
stripHTML(highlight);
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: hi praveen. thanks for your reply.. but it not works for me.. as you give me first example. i am getting dynamic generated div id. i can't handle this. and second code is also not working fine..

Comment: i am getting a variable "match". In this variable HTML is coming. how can i filter text using this variable.. can you give a suggestion. thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes.. this function gives me the exact string.. but my requirement is not fulfilled yet. becos i need to replace text in html and return back this html as like the highlight function do. You can see my live site that is [link](http://usrentacar.co.uk). you can find there a textbox for pickup location.

Comment: Okay, will work on that and update the answer. What am I supposed to click on your website? I see the pickup or drop details form.

Comment: Thanks @praveen kumar for your help and fast reply. Your function works for me..I am giving the solution for highlighting only text from HTML of Jquery Autocomplete. Now my code is as like :-
    `highlight: function(match, keywords) {
               var text= stripHTML(match);
               var replaced = text.replace(new RegExp("("+keywords+")", "gi"),'<b>$1</b>');
               return match.replace(stripHTML(match),replaced);
            }`