# Replace attribute in a HTML string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string with HTML in it. I want to replace the class attribute with the value in the data-class attribute (if any). This should apply to that particular tag/part of the HTML only.

I have written some of it, but would appreciate a pointer as to finish it:

```
html = "<div class='hello' data-class='class-name'>Content</div><div class='123'>Content</div><div data-class="class-111"></div>";

var html_out = $('<div/>').html(html).contents();

var final_html = $(html_out).find('[data-class]').attr('class', 'new-value');
```

So the above should return:

```
<div class='class-name' data-class='class-name'>Content</div><div class='123'>Content</div><div class="class-111" data-class="class-111"></div>
```

As for if it maintains the data-class part or removes it, that doesn't matter.

The key thing is that the HTML string will contain use of the data-class attribute and I need the class attribute to be overridden with this value.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095140/how-to-get-only-text-from-given-html-and-replace-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this has anything to do with it.

Comment: Indeed, this is definitely not a duplicate of the cited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('div[data-class]').attr('class', function() { return $(this).data('class') });
```

Comment: More elegant than my solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think this is what you're looking for -

```
html_out.find('[data-class]').each(function() {
    this.attr('class', this.attr('data-class');
})
```

Have a look at the [jquery docs on attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [attr function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this now, but looking at it I can't see how it picks up the value inside data-class. The value in data-class could be anything. This looks like it just adds the class named 'new_class', but I need it to get the class name in data-class and add that (and remove previous classes). Thanks for posting.

Comment: OK, I think I understand better what you're doing. give me a mo..

Comment: Thanks, both (this and the accepted answer) would work fine.